# How to restrict users to go to login page in codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter-3

I am new to php and codeigniter. I do not know how to restrict the user to go back to the login page once after successful log in process. I have created sessions also. 
    My sessions are created in model in the following way

```
$newdata = array(
                'id' => $query['entity_id'],
                'name' => $query['entity_name'],
                'uname' => $query['entity_uname']);
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);     }
```

I have heard of is_logged_in in ci, but i donot know how to implement/check using it in ci.
Any one can help me with your updated code.

My Login controller is as follows:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MY_Controller {
public function index()
{
$this->load->view('dashboard');
}
} ?>
```

And it comes here, after the model page where my session is been established

Comment: Do you want the user, not to go back once he is logged in?

Comment: @Keynes, the user should not come to login form page once he logs in . how can i restrict him to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check for user session like this

```
if($this->session->userdata('id')){
        redirect('profile', 'refresh');
}else{
    // load your login page
}
```

or add new key your session after successful login

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',true);
```

and check like this

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == true){
      redirect('profile', 'refresh');
}else{
     // load your login page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code

```
$newdata = array(
            'id' => $query['entity_id'],
            'name' => $query['entity_name'],
            'uname' => $query['entity_uname']
            );
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);                
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in','true');
```

Now your session is_logged_in variable value is true

controller code below:

```
class Login extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();  
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true){
       redirect('home');
    }
   else{
       redirect('login');
       }

   }

 }
```

This code will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login()
{
    // before rest of code here, check for existing session
    if ($this->session->has_userdata('id') && (int)$this->session->userdata('id') > 0) {
        // means user is logged in, redirect them to some logged in page in that case
        redirect('profile', 'refresh');
    }

    // here you write login method logic and check for credentials
}
```

Comment: With this code above, the user is logged in , that i have done already. But, the user is getting back to login page again now

Comment: Edit question and post your login method.

Comment: @Tpojka, He wants the user not to go back to login form page once he is logged in..

Comment: If not already, remove session library load from controllers and put it into autoload file. That way you couldn't forget to load session library somewhere. If database is used make for database the same.